# Looking for API (or solution) for generating PDF from online designer?

Tags: api, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

Working on building out a Web2Print product I need some kind of editor that will allow a user to manipulate graphics and ultimately generate a PDF.  There are plenty of HTML 2 PDF APIs available but I was hoping someone might have experience with something a little more integrated and suited for dealing with graphics/fonts/text?

Comment: Can you be more specific on your needs? You want a "[visual] editor" that allows "[end] users" to... "create/edit/design" their pages, and then generate PDF from them? Was are you expecting to be supplied from the web? Are "end users" using the editor from a web site? Or are they supplying content in a form to a prebuilt design template? What is the level of visual complexity that you are expecting for the pages? Are you building multiple page documeents?

Comment: Most of the PDF solutions I am finding are geared towards generating text-documents.  I have no need for multi-page.  I do need a visual editor that allows the end user to select a template, load that into an editor, customize a portion of text, add images, manipulate the text/fonts/colors/etc and then from that, generates a PDF file.  I could probably get by generating a high-resolution TIFF and using something on the back-end to embed this in a PDF but it needs to be accurate to the visual editor and/or live preview.

Comment: Here's an example of the type of product I have in mind -- http://www.esigns.com/template/pet-servcies/

Comment: There are several open source libraries and tools to generate PDF or high resolution images including both text, images, tables and so on. You might have a look at Apache FOP, LaTex (or other Tex variants), ImageMagick, and so on. However, the "web editor" part is the one that will pose issues. I know of no such "editor" that can be embeded in your own solution solution. Even on the commercial front, I know there are very few options.

Comment: Now, I don't want to push my luck, but my company does develop a complete page edition solution in Java (including a preferred CMS backend, but using it is optionnal). The editor could be embeded in a web page. If you are interested, though, please contact me personnaly.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP the best opensource option is TCPDF http://www.tcpdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to answer this and update everyone on the solutions that I found.  Through the Magento extension store I was able to find several commercial (although still very reasonably priced) solutions:

http://www.zetaprints.com/ and http://layoutbuddy.com/ look like the most full featured and supported (as well as no up-front licensing.)

Thanks for all of the responses!